# How to properly read in a .csv file and then populate a SQLite db using that data in python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

I am trying to populate a SQLite database using data from .csv files.  I am able to read in the data, but I am getting an error when trying to populate the SQLite db.

```
for ownerfile in ownerfile_list:
    if ownerfile.endswith(".csv"):
        each_file = (file_path + ownerfile)
        print(ownerfile) # file we're working on.

        with open(each_file, 'r', encoding = "UTF-8") as input_file : 

            next(input_file) # skip headers

            if not os.path.isdir(ownerfile) and not ownerfile.startswith("_"):

                for idx, line in enumerate(input_file.readlines()) :

                    line = line.strip().split(',')
                    cur.execute('''
                        INSERT INTO transactions (datetime,register_no,emp_no,
                          trans_no,upc,description,trans_type,trans_subtype,
                          trans_status,department,quantity,Scale,cost,unitPrice,
                          total,regPrice,altPrice,tax,taxexempt,foodstamp,wicable,
                          discount,memDiscount,discountable,discounttype,voided,percentDiscount,
                          ItemQtty,volDiscType,volume,
                          VolSpecial,mixMatch,matched,memType,staff,numflag,itemstatus,tenderstatus,
                          charflag,varflag,batchHeaderID,local,organic,display,receipt,
                          card_no,store,branch,match_id,trans_id)
                        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', line)   
db.commit()
```

I know the error has to do with the `line = line.strip().split(',')` line and that the insert statement is not reading the data correctly, but I am not sure how to fix it...

The error I am getting is:
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-01522ff3f449> in <module>()
     95                     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
     96                     ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,
---> 97                     ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', line)
     98

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 50, and there are 1 supplied.`

I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that when I `print(line)` I am getting `['']` as the first line. How do I get rid of this?

Comment: please post the full traceback of your error

Comment: Change `?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', line) ` to `?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', tuple(line)) `